# Why won't my navbar text colour change

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css. I'm trying to learn them but I have been having some issues. Basically I've been trying to create the website with the background image that has the navbar along the top (this works when previewing with brackets not yet here).

- Can I change the colour of the navbar?
- Also, how to have `h5` header centred on the left side of the page, with `h5` header below it, but as four lines, not as 2 long ones overlaying the image.

If anyone could help out that'd be great.

```css
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-width: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: rgba(150, 155, 155, );
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

}
.txtpic {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: http: //i.imgur.com/pE2NrKh.jpg;
  color: white;
}
.list {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">

  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Kyrgystan</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <title>Kyrgystan exped</title>
  <link href="Calums2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <img height="100%" src="http://i.imgur.com/pE2NrKh.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;" width="100%">
  <div class="list" style="Position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="group.html">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Krygyzstan</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="positions.html">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="positions.html">Expeditions</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <style>
      text-align:justify;
    </style>
      </div>
      
      
        <div class="txtpic" style="top: 100%;">
          <div class="row-sm-3"></div>
          <h3>Title is H3</h3>
          <h5>Text is h5.. We are a group of old school friends (plus a few others who tag along) who go on expeditions and good trips. We have over a thousand nights under canvas between us, and there are more in the pipeline. We have done trips on foot, by car, on water in the boat we built, by bicycle and even in a wooden burger cart. So far our outings have taken us across Europe, Asia and Africa.</h5>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change your navbar text color try with

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: red !important;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Let say this is the html markup

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="group.html">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Krygyzstan</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="positions.html">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="positions.html">Expeditions</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="list">

  <div class="txtpic" style="text-align: center">
    <h3>Title is H3</h3>
    <h5>Text is h5.. We are a group of old school friends (plus a few others who tag along) who go on expeditions and good trips. We have over a thousand nights under canvas between us, and there are more in the pipeline. We have done trips on foot, by car, on water in the boat we built, by bicycle and even in a wooden burger cart. So far our outings have taken us across Europe, Asia and Africa.</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

1- / youre previous code you was trying to put an image as an background with `img` element

1-1/ better way to do it with css just

```
.list {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/pE2NrKh.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

also you said that you cant change the color of your navbar text, you need to select the a element with  `.navbar-nav > li > a`

```
.navbar-nav > li a{
  color: white !important
}
```

Comment: it make you to access to all `a` element into `li` wich inside .navbar-nav

Comment: Hi @MagnusNicoll you are trying to make somthing like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbRpqQ ? if yes im gonna edit my answer and explain to you what i did

Comment: check the link again

Comment: Like that, but with the h3/h5 element having <div class="col-sm-3"> to make it at the left side, and ideally a bit further down

Comment: dont use col-sm-3 just play with `padding` of h1/h3 ( if you see my answer usefull press the green marker and feel free )

Comment: But I'm trying to have it such that it will work on both mobile and on laptop browser, so using px doesn't work does it? unfortunately I seem to be worse off - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVRpxJ

Answer (score 1):

For having the contents of h5 as 4 lines instead of the default way they appear try using the `<br>` tag. This tag breaks the line and starts a new line. So you could write it the following way:

```
<h5>Text is h5.. We are a group of old school friends (plus a few others who tag along) who go on expeditions and good trips.
    <br> We have over a thousand nights under canvas between us, and there are more in the pipeline.
    <br> We have done trips on foot, by car, on water in the boat we built, by bicycle and even in a wooden burger cart.
    <br> So far our outings have taken us across Europe, Asia and Africa.
</h5>
```

check out the following [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) to help you understand this tag better

The reason why this is not on top of the background image is that you have defined absolute positioning in the class 'txtpic'. try changing it to something else and tell me what happens.

Also the navbar background-color seems to change when i try to do so. If you want to change the text color use 'color:' instead of 'background-color'.